# Static files not found - Lighttpd with fastcgi fcgi

Tags: python, lighttpd, fastcgi

My python files are fun by fcgi without a problem, but my static content is producing 404 errors.

My fastcgi.conf:

```
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )
fastcgi.server = ("/" =>
    ((  
        "socket" => "/tmp/webxyz-fcgi.sock",
        "bin-path" => "/opt/local/www/xyz/webxyz.fcgi",
        "check-local" => "disable",
        "max-procs" => 1
    ))  
)

alias.url = ( 
    "/static" => "/opt/local/www/xyz/app/static"
)

url.rewrite-once = ( 
    #"^(/static($|/.*))$" => "$1",
    "^(/static.*)$" => "$1",
    "^(/.*)$" => "/webxyz.fcgi$1"
)
```

I have some debugging turned on:

```
debug.log-request-handling        = "enable"
debug.log-request-header-on-error = "enable"
debug.log-file-not-found          = "enable"
```

(though oddly file not found doesn't seem to do anything...)

Here's what I see in the error.log for one of the static files - all the others produce similar output (the ellipses below are a bunch more uninformative condition blocks that vary only in line number):

```
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.340) Request-URI     :  /static/bower_components/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.341) URI-scheme      :  http 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.342) URI-authority   :  75.101.102.25:8080 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.343) URI-path (raw)  :  /static/bower_components/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.344) URI-path (clean):  /static/bower_components/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.345) URI-query       :   
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block === 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.537) 1 (cached) result: false 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.249) run condition 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block === 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.273) 2 global/HTTPurl=~\.pdf$ nej 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.530) 1 (uncached) result: unknown 
...
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block === 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.467) HTTP["url"] ( /static/bower_components/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js ) compare to  \.pdf$ 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.530) 1 (uncached) result: false 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block === 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.537) 1 (cached) result: false 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.339) -- splitting Request-URI 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.340) Request-URI     :  /static/bower_components/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.341) URI-scheme      :  http 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.342) URI-authority   :  75.101.102.25:8080 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.343) URI-path (raw)  :  /static/bower_components/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.344) URI-path (clean):  /static/bower_components/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.345) URI-query       :   
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block === 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.537) 1 (cached) result: false 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block === 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.537) 1 (cached) result: false 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (mod_access.c.135) -- mod_access_uri_handler called 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block === 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.537) 1 (cached) result: false 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block === 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.537) 1 (cached) result: false 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (mod_fastcgi.c.3626) handling it in mod_fastcgi 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.473) -- before doc_root 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.474) Doc-Root     : /opt/local/www/htdocs 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.475) Rel-Path     : /static 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.476) Path         :  
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.524) -- after doc_root 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.525) Doc-Root     : /opt/local/www/htdocs 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.526) Rel-Path     : /static 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.527) Path         : /opt/local/www/htdocs/static 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block === 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.537) 1 (cached) result: false 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.544) -- logical -> physical 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.545) Doc-Root     : /opt/local/www/htdocs 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.546) Basedir      : /opt/local/www/xyz/app/static 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.547) Rel-Path     : /static 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.548) Path         : /opt/local/www/xyz/app/static 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block === 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.537) 1 (cached) result: false 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (response.c.249) run condition 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block === 
2014-04-27 15:20:24: (configfile-glue.c.273) 2 global/HTTPurl=~\.pdf$ nej 
...
```

The last path it's looking at, /opt/local/www/xyz/app/static is my static directory, and contains bower_components/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js

I'm not sure why it's not being found - the permissions are fine:

```
sudo -u www cat /opt/local/www/xyz/app/static/bower_components/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js
```

works as expected.

Any guidance or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.

So reading [this](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/1420) post, I see that my use of the werkzeug.contrib.fixers.CGIRootFix has led me to define the scope of my fcgi as "/", which takes precedence over the url and rewrite rules for "/static".  Wrapping the fcgi server in a condition to exclude requests for urls beginning with "/static" fixes the problem with no static content being served.

Here's the working fastcgi.conf:

```
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )
$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/static" {
    fastcgi.server = ("/" =>
        ((  
            "socket" => "/tmp/webpdb-fcgi.sock",
            "bin-path" => "/opt/local/www/xyz/webxyz.fcgi",
            "check-local" => "disable",
            "max-procs" => 1
        ))  
    )   
}

alias.url = ( 
    "/static" => "/opt/local/www/xyz/app/static"
)

url.rewrite-once = ( 
    #"^(/static($|/.*))$" => "$1",
    "^(/static.*)$" => "$1",
    "^(/.*)$" => "/webxyz.fcgi$1"
)
```